# How to solve JavaFX ProgressIndicator repainting issues while downloading?

Tags: java, javafx

I am downloading file from ftp client with that loop

```
private void download(String date){
    try {
        FTPFile ftpFile = client.mlistFile(filename());
        long ftpFileSize = ftpFile.getSize();
        frame.setMaximumProgress((int) ftpFileSize);
        File downloadFile = new File(folder + filename());
        OutputStream outputStream2 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile));
        InputStream inputStream = client.retrieveFileStream(fileName);
        byte[] bytesArray = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        int bytes = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(bytesArray)) != -1){
            outputStream2.write(bytesArray, 0, bytesRead);
            bytes += bytesRead;
        }
        if (client.completePendingCommand()){
            outputStream2.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Downloading error.");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if(e instanceof FTPConnectionClosedException){
            reconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

ProgressIndicator just still on one position.
Method setProgress successfully priniting that progress.

```
public void setProgress(double value){
    System.out.println(value);
    progress.setProgress(value);
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `setProgress()` ?

Comment: Inner class Logs of class LogsViewer.

Comment: Is the while loop running on JavaFX Application thread?

Comment: You cannot update the value of a JavaFX control on any other thread. You can use `Platform.runLater(() -> {  progress.setProgress(ivalue); });`, but the best way to achieve this has been already answered and you would want to give it a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a [Task Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) as it was meant to, no need to reinvent the wheel..

```
public class DownloadTask extends Task<Void> {
  public Void call() {
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(bytesArray)) != -1){
      outputStream2.write(bytesArray, 0, bytesRead);
      bytes += bytesRead;
      updateProgress(bytes, ftpFileSize);
    }
  }
}
```

and bind the `progressProperty()` of the `Task` to the `progressProperty()` of your `ProgressIndicator`.

Example on how to bind the two properties:

```
ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator();
DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
progress.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
new Thread(task).start();
```

Comment: Can you add more details about **binding**?

Comment: @Aero see my example.

Comment: thanks for example.
I just put whole download method to question.
If you will help me to reorganize that to **Task** model - I will be very happy.
Because I don't understand how to...

Comment: I'm afraid, that is not what StackOverflow is meant for.. You asked a question, you got an answer. If you now need to refactor some parts of your code you should figure it out on your own, shouln't be that hard ;-)  Even if I wanted to help you refactor your code, I couldn't because there are too many references in your code which I do not know..

Comment: Ok. Thanks one more time.