# How to implement a ProgressBar while persisting into a database

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar, progress-indicator

I would like to implement a ProgressBar and ProgressIndicator while persisting into a database, to visualize what has already been persisted, and what is remaining. The problem is that I can't find a way to find the amount of time remaining for the persistence to complete.

```
ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(0.6);
ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator(0.6);
```

How can I determine the amount of time remaining? I just can't seem to find a way to relate it with the database progress.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092904/how-to-solve-javafx-progressindicator-repainting-issues-while-downloading/29093377#29093377

Answer (score 0):

You can extrapolate. E. g. you performed 3 out of 10 persist operations and that took 3 seconds. Then about 7 seconds left. Of course it is rough approximation.

Comment: No idea why this answer is downvoted... it describes the only possible solution for most cases.

Comment: It only works if you are performing multiple operations.  For one large database operation, there is no way to estimate the time to completion.